# How can I do the opposite of value_counts (i.e. get a dataframe column with repeated values using the column of counts)?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that has two columns and looks something like this:

| diameter | counts |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | 3 |
| 2.3 | 1 |
| 3.0 | 1 |
| 5.0 | 2 |
| 10.0 | 1 |

I want it to be reformatted so that I have a full list of the occurences of each 'diameter'. In other words, want to generate an output (for example an array) that looks like this:

**[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.3, 3.0, 5.0, 5.0, 10.0]**

It could also be a dataframe, the format doesn't matter, I just don't know how to go from counts to original list (whereas list of occurences to counts is very easy with value_counts!).

Maybe I could loop through each row and then print that value X times, but I'm not sure how to do this exactly.
E.g. for example I could do

```
for row in df.rows:
        N = (counts[row])
        for i in range(N):
                print(diameter[row])
```

but am having a hard time figuring out how to consolidate this and make it work.

Any help very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possible solution, which uses [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
np.repeat(df.diameter, df.counts).values
```

Output:

```
array([ 1.1,  1.1,  1.1,  2.3,  3. ,  5. ,  5. , 10. ])
```

---

In case, a dataframe is needed:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'diameter': np.repeat(df.diameter, df.counts),
     'counts': [1] * df.counts.sum()})
```

Output:

```
   diameter  counts
0       1.1       1
1       1.1       1
2       1.1       1
3       2.3       1
4       3.0       1
5       5.0       1
6       5.0       1
7      10.0       1
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I actually really liked your first response:
out = np.repeat(df.diameter.values, df.counts.values)
I will leave it here as well, in case just having the array is helpful to others

Comment: In the end the array is what I really wanted, so this means I don't have to go through the trouble of dropping columns and indeces etc.

Comment: I have just updated my answer to have the solution which returns only the array, @g.is.stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) a count of 1:

```
out = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['counts'])]
         .assign(counts=1) # or .drop(columns='counts')
       )
```

Output:

```
   diameter  counts
0       1.1       1
0       1.1       1
0       1.1       1
1       2.3       1
2       3.0       1
3       5.0       1
3       5.0       1
4      10.0       1
```